# How to control a MediaElement inside of a VisualBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have a MediaElement inside of a VisualBrush object so that I can run multiple video displays while only using one MediaElement.  The problem is that I cannot figure out how to control the MediaElement from the code behind.  The code behind doesn't recognize the name 'myMedia'.

How do I access this element?

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="Media" Stretch="Uniform">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <MediaElement Name="myMedia" Source="c:\a.mp4" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get resources by key from an element in code behind via the [**`FrameworkElement.Resources` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources(v=vs.110).aspx). Then it is just a matter of casting the returned resource to a `VisualBrush` and accessing and casting its [**`VisualBrush.Visual` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.visual(v=vs.110).aspx).

**VB.NET:**

```vb
Dim VBrush As VisualBrush = TryCast(Me.Resources("Media"), VisualBrush)

If VBrush IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim Media As MediaElement = TryCast(VBrush.Visual, MediaElement)

    If Media IsNot Nothing Then
        'Do your stuff here...
    End If
End If
```

**C#:**

```cs
VisualBrush VBrush = this.Resources["Media"] as VisualBrush;

if(VBrush != null) {
    MediaElement media = VBrush.Visual as MediaElement;

    if(media != null) {
        //Do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

Comment: @nikotromus : Glad I could help! Happy coding! ;)